# gtx 580, microphone not recognized on windows 7, how to get it working?

Tags: audio-recording

i have a hdmi connection to my monitor with a gtx 580 graphics card. there's no mic showing up when i plug it in to the monitor or to the pc. there's no audio input on the card but it says it's 'internal AUX input'?

how can i get the microphone working on this computer?

Comment: Why are you talking about microphones and speaker when your asking about a graphics card?  What does the graphic card have to do with your problem?

Comment: it's connected to my monitor using hdmi connection. wasn't sure if the mic connected to my monitor would work. it's not showing up

Comment: You cannot hook a microphone over an HDMI connection.  Connect it directly to your microphone port on your pc.

Comment: hey guys I have done that. I plugged it into the audio input (pink socket) but the microphone is still not showing up. when I go to Sound and check show disabled devices or show disconnected devices, it only shows Internal AUX Jack, and no microphone.

Comment: Where are you looking exactly for it to show up?  What sound device do you have exactly?  Do you have the current drivers for that device installed?

Comment: i only have a hdmi monitor and it outputs audio through that. i have audio jack input but when i plug it in it doesn't recognize the microphone. i dont have drivers (don't know what to get)

Comment: Your monitor ony has the ability to play sounds ( speakers ).  We need to know what audio device your PC has in order to determine how to enable the microphone.  We don't need to know anything about your monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound when i go to device mnanager it shows me several NVIDIA High Definition Audio. There's also realtek high definition audio but it is disabled

Comment: okay when ienabled that realtek high def audio, it shows up my microphone! but i can't hear sound from the monitor

Comment: If you cannot hear sound from your monitor then you have not plugged the monitor to your PC.  The hdmi is not going to transmit the sound.

Comment: sweet its working but i can't hear my own voice. which i think is a good thing? lol

Answer (score 0):

The jack on your monitor is an audio ouput to connect headphones.

The HDMI connection carries PC audio to the monitor, so no wonder your microphone is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't connect your microphone to the screen.

There is a pink connector on the back of your PC.
Plug your microphone to that connector and it should work.